# Эстетичное форматирование json файла

Tags: java, json, форматирование, gson

Я использую библиотеку `Gson` для сериализации в `json`. Делаю я примерно вот так:

```
new Gson().toJson(new MyObject());
```

Но при этом у меня получается одна единая строка, без отступов и переносов:

```
{"classes":[{"name":"warrior","skills":[]}]}
```

Каким образом можно форматировать эту строку в более эстетичный вид, при сериализации, что бы потом можно было удобно менять значения? Та строка должна быть примерно такая:

```
{
    "classes":
    [
        {
            "name": "warrior",
            "skills": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Для написания кода есть сайт Pojo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Добавьте настройку в билдер, а не просто создавайте инстанс `Gson` через конструктор:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(new MyObject());
```